# Tricky "grouped" ordering in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Been having trouble with this for some time.

I have a database sort of like this:

```
Car_ID   Car_Brand   Car_Model   Car_Price
   1     Ford        Fiesta       4000
   2     Ford        Mustang     29000
   3     Ford        Focus       12000
   4     Honda       Civic       15000
   6     Honda       Jazz         5000
   7     Toyota      Prius       14000
```

I want to perform a search that finds the cheapest car then orders the rest of the cars of the same brand by price ascending.

I want my output to be this:

```
Car_ID   Car_Brand   Car_Model   Car_Price
   1     Ford        Fiesta       4000
   3     Ford        Focus       12000
   2     Ford        Mustang     29000
   6     Honda       Jazz         5000
   4     Honda       Civic       15000
   7     Toyota      Prius       14000
```

The cheapest car is the Ford Fiesta so that and the rest of the Ford models follow it directly ordered by price. Honda then has the second cheapest model so the Jazz and the rest of the Hondas follow and so on.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd like it to be ordered as I posted it. So all ordered by price ascending but ultimately grouped and ordered by brand with cheapest price if you see what I mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is create a transient data set that contains car_brand and the lowest price for that brand (which I'll call brand_price), then JOIN that data back to your original cars table.  This will give you the additional piece of information (brand_price) that you need to sort the data:

```
 SELECT car_id, car_brand, car_model, price FROM cars C1
    JOIN (select car_brand, MIN(price) AS brand_price FROM cars GROUP BY car_brand) C2
      ON C1.car_brand = C2.car_brand
    ORDER BY C2.brand_price, C1.car_brand, C1.price
```

Comment: +1 took me two tries to understand, hence the deleted comment

Comment: +1 And how much easier it would be with windowed functions! `SELECT car_id, car_brand, car_model, price FROM cars ORDER BY MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY car_brand), car_brand, price`. Oh well...

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work with a few tweaks to match my real database, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Cars a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Car_Brand, MIN(Car_Price) AS MinPrice
    FROM Cars
    GROUP BY Car_Brand
  ) b ON a.Car_Brand = b.Car_Brand
ORDER BY b.MinPrice, a.Car_Price
```

Comment: +1, although I would probably use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. Still both should work all right.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a min grouped by Car_Brand order by the min price and then do a join ordered by the  sorted car_brand and price. I will see if I can get the query done for this.

Answer (score -2):

I think you will be able to do that with the following query

```
SELECT Car_ID, Car_Brand, Car_Model, Car_Price 
FROM tblcars
ORDER BY Car_Price, Car_Brand
```

unless I missed something

Comment: They should be grouped by the brand as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from cars order by  Car_Price, Car_Brand ASC
```